# How to pass properties from parent to child in Redirect

Tags: reactjs, react-router, create-react-app, react-router-dom

I am learning ReactJS and now doing a small project for myself to manage my recipes.

I create my project using `npx create-react-app <my-app>`. I display a gallery of my recipe, each recipe has an image, name, description and duration of preparation. By clicking a recipe another page will open with the details of the recipe with a list of the ingredients and preparation steps. I have the gallery page running and when clicking a recipe the details page is opening, but it doesn't get the property of the recipe that I pass to it.

My application/project components:
App.js

```
    import React from 'react';
    import logo from './logo.svg';
    import './App.css';
    import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
    import HomePage from './pages/HomePage';
    import LoginPage from './pages/LoginPage';
    import RecipesPage from './pages/RecipesPage';
    import RecipeDetailsPage from './pages/RecipeDetailsPage';
    import PlannedDinnerPage from './pages/PlannedDinnerPage';
    import ShoppingListPage from './pages/ShoppingListPage';
    import jsonUsers from './data/users'
    import jsonKitchens from './data/Kitchens'
    import jsonDishTypes from './data/DishTypes'
    import jsonIngredients from './data/Ingredient'
    import jsonRecipes from './data/recipes'
    import jsonRecipeIngredients from './data/RecipeIngrediaent'
    import jsonRecipesPreperationSteps from './data/RecipePreperationStep'

    class App extends React.Component {

      constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this.state = {
            recipeId: null,
            activeUser: null,
            allUsers: jsonUsers,
            allKitchens: jsonKitchens,
            allDishTypes: jsonDishTypes,
            allIngredients: jsonIngredients,
            allRecipes: jsonRecipes,
            allRecipesIngredients: jsonRecipeIngredients,
            allRecipesPreperationSteps: jsonRecipesPreperationSteps,
            activeUserRecipes: []
            // hack for starting with my recipes
            // activeUserRecipes: jsonRecipes.filter(recipe => recipe.userId === 1)
         }

         this.handleLogout = this.handleLogout.bind(this);
         this.handleLogin = this.handleLogin.bind(this);
         this.addRecipe = this.addRecipe.bind(this);

         console.log(this.state.allRecipes);
      }

      handleLogout() {
         this.setState({ activeUser: null });
      }

      handleLogin(activeUser) {
         const activeUserRecipes = this.state.allRecipes.filter(recipe => recipe.userId === activeUser.id)
         this.setState({ activeUser, activeUserRecipes });
      }

      addRecipe(newRecipe) {
         //const {activeUser, allRecipes, activeUserRecipes} this.state.activeUser
         // 1) add id and user to the recipe
         newRecipe.userId = this.state.activeUser.id;
         newRecipe.id = this.state.allRecipes[this.state.allRecipes.length - 1].id + 1;

         // 2) update all recipes and active user recipes
         const allRecipes = this.state.allRecipes.concat(newRecipe);
         const activeUserRecipes = this.state.activeUserRecipes.concat(newRecipe);

         this.setState({ allRecipes, activeUserRecipes });
      }

      render() {

         // const activeUser = this.state.activeUser;
         const { recipeId, activeUser, allUsers,
            allRecipes,
            allKitchens,
            allDishTypes,
            allIngredients,
            allRecipesIngredients,
            allRecipesPreperationSteps,
            activeUserRecipes } = this.state;

         return (
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/">
                 <HomePage activeUser={activeUser} handleLogout={this.handleLogout} />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/login">
                 <LoginPage users={allUsers} handleLogin={this.handleLogin} />
              </Route>
              <Route exact path="/recipes">
                 <RecipesPage activeUser={activeUser} addRecipe={this.addRecipe} allRecipes={allRecipes} handleLogout={this.handleLogout} userRecipes={activeUserRecipes} />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/recipes/:id">
                 <RecipeDetailsPage activeUser={activeUser} addRecipe={this.addRecipe} allRecipes={allRecipes} handleLogout={this.handleLogout} userRecipes={activeUserRecipes} />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/dinner">
                 <PlannedDinnerPage activeUser={activeUser} addRecipe={this.addRecipe} allRecipes={activeUserRecipes} handleLogout={this.handleLogout} />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/shopping">
                 <ShoppingListPage activeUser={activeUser} addRecipe={this.addRecipe} allRecipes={allRecipes} handleLogout={this.handleLogout} userRecipes={activeUserRecipes} />
              </Route>
            </Switch>
         );
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

RecipesPage.js
        import React from 'react'
        import RecipesNavbar from '../components/RecipesNavbar'
        import { Container, Row, Col, Button, Modal, Form } from 'react-bootstrap'
        import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
        import RecipeCard from '../components/RecipeCard'

```
    class RecipesPage extends React.Component {
         constructor(props) {
              super(props);
              this.state = {
                    navigateToRecipeId: null,
                    showModal: false
              }

              this.openModal = this.openModal.bind(this);
              this.closeModal = this.closeModal.bind(this);
              this.createRecipe = this.createRecipe.bind(this);
              this.openRecipeDetails = this.openRecipeDetails.bind(this);

              this.nameInput = React.createRef();
              this.descInput = React.createRef();
              this.imgInput = React.createRef();
         }

         openRecipeDetails() {
              let navigateToRecipeId = this.props.recipeData.id;
              this.setState({ navigateToRecipeId });
         }

         openModal() {
              this.setState({ showModal: true })
         }

         closeModal() {
              this.setState({ showModal: false })
         }

         createRecipe() {
              const newRecipe = {
                    name: this.nameInput.current.value,
                    desc: this.descInput.current.value,
                    img: this.imgInput.current.value,
              }

              this.props.addRecipe(newRecipe);
              this.closeModal();
         }

         /*
              activeUser={activeUser} 
              addRecipe={this.addRecipe} 
              allRecipes={allRecipes} 
              handleLogout={this.handleLogout} 
              recipe={recipe} 
              recipeId={recipeId} 
              userRecipes={activeUserRecipes} 
          */
         render() {
              const { activeUser, handleLogout, allRecipes } = this.props;
              const { recipeId, userRecipes } = this.props;
              const { showModal } = this.state;

              if (!activeUser) {
                    return <Redirect to="/" />
              }

              const recipesCards = allRecipes.map(recipe =>
                    <Col key={recipe.id} lg="3" md="6">
                         <RecipeCard activeUser={activeUser} recipe={recipe} recipeData={recipe} />
                    </Col>
              );

              return (
                    <div>
                         <RecipesNavbar activeUser={activeUser} handleLogout={handleLogout} />
                         <Container>
                              <div className="recipes-header">
                                    <h1>{activeUser.fname}'s Recipes</h1>
                                    <Button variant="primary" onClick={this.openModal}>New Recipe</Button>
                              </div>
                              <Row>
                                    {recipesCards}
                              </Row>
                         </Container>


                         <Modal show={showModal} onHide={this.closeModal} size="lg">
                              <Modal.Header closeButton>
                                    <Modal.Title>New Recipe</Modal.Title>
                              </Modal.Header>
                              <Modal.Body>
                                    <Form>
                                         <Form.Group as={Row} controlId="formHorizontalEmail">
                                              <Form.Label column sm={2}>
                                                    Name
                                              </Form.Label>
                                              <Col sm={10}>
                                                    <Form.Control ref={this.nameInput} type="text" placeholder="Recipe name" />
                                              </Col>
                                         </Form.Group>

                                         <Form.Group as={Row} controlId="formHorizontalPassword">
                                              <Form.Label column sm={2}>
                                                    Description
                                              </Form.Label>
                                              <Col sm={10}>
                                                    <Form.Control ref={this.descInput} type="text" placeholder="Recipe description" />
                                              </Col>
                                         </Form.Group>

                                         <Form.Group as={Row} controlId="formHorizontalPassword">
                                              <Form.Label column sm={2}>
                                                    Image URL
                                              </Form.Label>
                                              <Col sm={10}>
                                                    <Form.Control ref={this.imgInput} type="text" placeholder="Recipe image URL" />
                                              </Col>
                                         </Form.Group>

                                    </Form>
                              </Modal.Body>
                              <Modal.Footer>
                                    <Button variant="secondary" onClick={this.closeModal}>
                                         Close
                                    </Button>
                                    <Button variant="primary" onClick={this.createRecipe}>
                                         Create Recipe
                                    </Button>
                              </Modal.Footer>
                         </Modal>

                    </div>
              );
         }
    }

    export default RecipesPage;
```

RecipeCard.js

```
    import React from 'react'
    import { Card } from 'react-bootstrap'
    import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

    class RecipeCard extends React.Component {
         constructor(props) {
              super(props);
              this.state = {
                    navigateToRecipeId: null,
                    recipeId: null,
                    recipe: null,
                    recipeData: null,
              }
              this.openRecipeDetails = this.openRecipeDetails.bind(this);
         }

         openRecipeDetails() {
              console.log("openRecipeDetails - RecipeId: " + this.props.recipe.id);
              let { navigateToRecipeId, recipe, recipeData } = this.state;
              navigateToRecipeId = this.props.recipe.id;
              recipe = this.props.recipe;
              recipeData = this.props.recipe;
              // this.state.recipeDetails = from data files / database;
              this.setState({ navigateToRecipeId, recipeData });
         }

         render() {
              const { activeUser, recipe, activeUserRecipes, recipeData } = this.props;
              const { navigateToRecipeId } = this.state;
              /*
                    activeUser={activeUser} 
                    addRecipe={this.addRecipe}
                    allRecipes={allRecipes} 
                    handleLogout={this.handleLogout} 
                    recipe={recipe} 
                    recipeId={recipeId} 
                    userRecipes={activeUserRecipes} 
              */
              if (this.state.navigateToRecipeId != null) {
                    const { navigateToRecipeId } = this.state;
                    return (
                         <Redirect to={'/recipes/' + this.state.navigateToRecipeId} activeUser={activeUser} recipe={recipeData} recipeData={recipeData} recipeId={navigateToRecipeId} recipe={recipe} userRecipes={activeUserRecipes}  />
                    );
              } else {
                    return (
                         <Card className="recipe" >
                              <Card.Img onClick={this.openRecipeDetails} variant="top" src={recipeData.img} />
                              <Card.Body>
                                    <Card.Title>{recipeData.name}</Card.Title>
                                    <Card.Subtitle>{recipeData.desc}</Card.Subtitle>
                                    <Card.Text>Cooking Time: {recipeData.duration} min</Card.Text>
                              </Card.Body>
                         </Card>
                    );
              }
         }
    }

    export default RecipeCard;
```

RecipeDetailsPage.js

```
    import React from 'react'
    import { Jumbotron, Button, Container } from 'react-bootstrap'
    import RecipesNavbar from '../components/RecipesNavbar';

    class RecipeDetailsPage extends React.Component {
         constructor(props) {
              super(props);
              this.state = {
                    navigateToRecipeId: null,
                    recipeId: null,
                    recipe: null,
                    recipeData: null,
              }
         }
    /*
         activeUser={activeUser} 
         allRecipes={allRecipes} 
         userRecipes={activeUserRecipes} 
         recipeId={recipeId} 
         handleLogout={this.handleLogout} 
         addRecipe={this.addRecipe}
     */
         componentDidMount() {
              console.log("RecipeDetailsPage.componentDidMount() -- recipeId = ?");
              console.log("RecipeDetailsPage.componentDidMount() -- recipeId: " + this.props.recipe.id);
              let recipeId = this.props.match.params.id;
         }

         render() {
              const { activeUser, handleLogout } = this.props;

              return (
                    <div>
                         <RecipesNavbar activeUser={activeUser} handleLogout={handleLogout} />
                         <Jumbotron>
                              <Container>
                                    <h1 className="display-3">Show Details of Selected Recipe</h1>
                                    <div>Name: &lt; R e c i p e   N a m e &gt;</div>
                                    <div>Description:  &lt; R e c i p e   D e s c r i p t i o n &gt;</div>
                                    <div>Duration:  &lt; (nnn) min &gt;</div>
                                    <div>Kitchen:  &lt; K i t c h e n   i t   B e l o n g s   T o &gt;</div>
                                    <div>Type:  &lt; R e c i p e   T y p e &gt;</div>
                              </Container>
                         </Jumbotron>
                    </div>
              );
         }
    }

    export default RecipeDetailsPage;
```

In `RecipeCard.js` at the `Redirect` I see the values of the properties I want to send, but in `RecipeDetailsPage.js` in the `constructor` immediatlly after invoking `super(props)` I don't see the properties I sent in the redirect, only those I have in the `App.js` in `Route` of the `RecipeDetailsPage` component.

I am looking in google for a hint, but all I found thus far is about seding properties with `Route` (I am still searching).

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing? Is my practice correct or should I do it in a different way?

Comment: I dont think sending props to a component via a redirect is a good idea, I mean your app's logic would be super messy like that. Why dont you just use redux or the context api to pass some data from one spot to the other like you're describing. Without needing to bank off of a Redirect

Comment: I wouldn't use redirect for this purpose. It sounds like you want to use the [Link](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link) component instead on your recipe card to navigate to the recipes page. When you load your recipes page, fetch the recipe data using the `:id` parameter in the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [John Ruddell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2733506/john-ruddell) and [Dennis Martinez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/613932/dennis-martinez), you gave me very useful tips which led me to the solution I needed.

I don't use `Redux` in this project as it's the next thing for me to learn, in this exercise I want to practice `react-router` and `react-router-dom`. I use `context API` in another part of my application and the same goes for using the `Link` component.

Here is the solution I found that works:

App.js

```
    {/* Commenting the old code, followed by the code that works;
    <Route path="/recipes/:id">
        <RecipeDetailsPage activeUser={activeUser} addRecipe={this.addRecipe} allRecipes={allRecipes} handleLogout={this.handleLogout} userRecipes={activeUserRecipes} />
    </Route> 
    */}
    <Route path="/recipes/:id" component={RecipeDetailsPage} activeUser={activeUser} allRecipes={allRecipes} />
```

When using `<Route path=".." component={..}... />` in the `RecipeDetailsPage` I get the `:id` in `this.props.match.params.id` and can retrieve the rest of the details I need from the database using a REST API GET request. That's what I needed.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. As a side note, you can use the original route code you had and use the [hook](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks) api provider by react-router-dom to tap in to the `:id` parameter `const { id } = useParams()` if you wanted to still use that way, which is actually encouraged by the developers of react-router-dom. Read more on that in their [v5.1 blog post](https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v5-1/)

Comment: What I am missing in learning React is the best practices side, how developers do things? and how it's recommended to do things the right way? There are a lot of tutorials, but not a lot of them touch this topic.